# Combine columns from tables into single table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

I have four tables with data I want to put the respective total columns from each in a different column. However, I would like to match on `dealerId`. So if there is a dealerId in Table 1 and Table 3 that are the same, they should be a single row.

Table 1

```
dealerId | t1 Total Amount
---------+---------------
1        |  123
2        |  456
```

Table 2

```
dealerId | t2 Total Amount
---------+----------------
3        | 111
4        | 222
5        | 333
```

Table 3

```
dealerId | t3 Total Amount
---------+----------------
1        | 555
3        | 565
6        | 888
```

Table 4

```
dealerId | t4 Total Amount
---------+----------------
1        | 88
2        | 99
3        | 11
```

Desired Outcome

```
dealerId | t1Total Amount | t2Total Amount | t3 Total Amount | t4 Total Amount
---------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------
1        | 123            |  null          | 555             | 88
2        | 456            |  null          | null            | 99
3        | null           |  111           | 565             | 11
4        | null           |  222           | null            | null
5        | null           |  333           | null            | null
6        | null           |  null          | 888             | null
```

I have basically created views (I don't know if this is the correct term for it) and tried to UNION ALL them, but this only gives me a single column with all the totals.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT o.DealerId, Sum(oi.Amount) as T1_Total
FROM ....
) AS T1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT o.DealerId, Sum(oi.Amount) as T2_Total
FROM ....
) AS T2
UNION ALL
...
-- repeat for T3 and T4
```

Comment: Probably should look up what `UNION ALL` does.

Comment: @Eric that may be. And I did before this, but didn't know how to move on from what I actually wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the [`pivot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) operator:

```sql
select dealerId, T1, T2, T3, T4
from (
    select dealerId, 'T1' as Src, "t1 Total Amount" as Amt from T1
    union all
    select dealerId, 'T2'       , "t2 Total Amount"        from T2
    union all
    select dealerId, 'T3'       , "t3 Total Amount"        from T3
    union all
    select dealerId, 'T4'       , "t4 Total Amount"        from T4
     ) vert
pivot (sum(Amt) for Src in (T1,T2,T3,T4)) horiz
```

Results:

```
   dealerId          T1          T2          T3          T4
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
          1         123        NULL         555          88
          2         456        NULL        NULL          99
          3        NULL         111         565          11
          4        NULL         222        NULL        NULL
          5        NULL         333        NULL        NULL
          6        NULL        NULL         888        NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something like this:

```
  with all_dealer_ids AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT dealerId
    FROM Table1 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT dealerId
    FROM Table2
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT dealerId
    FROM Table3
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT dealerId
    FROM Table4 
  )

  SELECT adi.dealerId, SUM(t1.TotalAmount) As T1TotalAmount, SUM(t2.TotalAmount) As 
    T2TotalAmount, SUM(t3.TotalAmount) AS T3TotalAmount, SUM(t4.TotalAmount) AS T4TotalAmount
  FROM all_dealer_ids adi
  LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
    ON adi.dealerId = t1.dealerId
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON adi.dealerId = t2.dealerId
  LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
    ON adi.dealerId = t3.dealerId
  LEFT JOIN Table4 t4
    ON adi.dealerId = t4.dealerId
  GROUP BY adi.dealerId
  ORDER BY adi.dealerId ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use JOIN instead of UNION to accomplish what you're looking for. UNIONs are typically used to stack data, which is why you are seeing all your data in one column. You can try something like this to accomplish what you are looking for.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1_totals.dealerID, t2_totals.dealerID, t3_totals.dealerID, t4_totals.dealerID) AS dealerId
     , t1_totals.t1_total_amount
     , t2_totals.t2_total_amount
     , t3_totals.t3_total_amount
     , t4_totals.t4_total_amount
    FROM (
       SELECT dealerID, sum(amount) AS t1_total_amount FROM t1 GROUP BY t1.dealerID
     ) AS t1_totals
    FULL JOIN (
       SELECT dealerID, sum(amount) AS t2_total_amount FROM t2 GROUP BY t2.dealerID
     ) AS t2_totals
         ON t2_totals.dealerID = t1_totals.dealerID
    FULL JOIN (
       SELECT dealerID, sum(amount) AS t3_total_amount FROM t3 GROUP BY t3.dealerID
     ) AS t3_totals
         ON t3_totals.dealerID = t1_totals.dealerID
    FULL JOIN (
       SELECT dealerID, sum(amount) AS t4_total_amount FROM t4 GROUP BY t4.dealerID
     ) AS t4_totals
         ON t4_totals.dealerID = t1_totals.dealerID
ORDER BY dealerId
```

[image]